# sum volume per day in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have this SQL table with three columns,

```
startdate     enddate         volume
2015-01-05     2015-01-12       50
2015-01-10     2015-01-15       20
```

now I want to sum the total volume per calendar day,
I thought I build a calendar table and then per day I'd

```
select sum(volume) as volsum
group by calendar.date
```

to get

```
date          volsum
2015-01-01     50
2015-01-02     50
...
...
...
2015-01-10     70
...
...
2015-01-15     20
```

But I don't know how to join the two tables. Any ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: thx for that, how do I get this table layout?

Comment: You select the text, and click the `{}` symbol

Comment: or select text and hit Ctrl+k

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use the calendar table as source of dates and use a left join to get all dates from the calendar table even if there are no data for the volume for that date. Do this:

```
select 
  calendar.date, sum(volume) as volsum
from 
  calendar
left join 
  your_table t on calendar.date >= t.startdate 
              and calendar.date <= t.enddate
group by 
  calendar.date
```

If you want to limit the dates returned from the calendar table you could add a `where` clause like:

```
where calendar.date >= (select MIN(startdate) from your_table)
  and calendar.date <= (select MAX(enddate) from your_table)
```